# C: What is the effect/meaning of declaring a variable after it is used?

Tags: c, syntax

I am reading [Ken Thompson's *Reflections on Trusting Trust*](https://www.archive.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf) and have come across a piece of example code that I don't quite understand (Figures 3.*).

**Figure 3.1:**

```
compile(s)
char *s;
{
    ...
}
```

**Figure 3.2:**

```
compile(s)
char *s;
{
    if (match(s, "pattern")) {
        compile("bug");
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Figure 3.3:**

```
compile(s)
char *s;
{
    if (match(s, "pattern1")) {
        compile("bug1");
        return;
    }
    if (match(s, "pattern2")) {
        compile("bug2");
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

What is the meaning of `char s[];` after `compile(s)`?

Also, why is there a block of code that doesn't belong to a function initialisation or if/else/while/do statement?

Comment: I'm seeing `char *s;` in the link not `char s[];` if I'm not wrong. Note that both `char *s` and `char s[]` are different except in function arguments.

Comment: @Achal As a function parameter (and only as a function parameter) they're the same.

Comment: Agree @SteveSummit

Comment: Please remove the semicolons in the first line. They are not in the linked paper.

Comment: There is no semicolon after `compile(s);`. Please copy the examples verbatim.

Comment: The code excerpts in the question do not accurately reproduce those in the linked paper, which make the question largely moot.  If you want to ask about the code in the paper, then present ***that*** code.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old, obsolete syntax for declaring the type of the parameters of a function. You declare the types of the parameters after the line that contains the name of the function and its parameters, but before the opening brace that starts the body of the function.

```
compile(s)
    char *s;
{
    /* function body goes here */
}
```

The reason for this weird syntax is that it evolved from [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)), a predecessor of C, which did not have any type declarations: a variable was a machine word (a “cell”), and it was up to the programmer to use it correctly. See “The Problems of B” in [“The Development of the C language” by Dennis Ritchie](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html). With no types, to define a function, you'd just write

```
compile(s)
{
    /* function body goes here */
}
```

In early C, parameter declarations were optional, so existing code kept working. If something's type wasn't declared, it defaulted to `int`.

This declaration syntax is part of the first version of the C language, called [K&R C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K&R_C) after the authors of the seminal book about C, Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie. In the late 1980s and 1990s, there was a gradual move to a newer version of the language called [ANSI C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) or C89 or C90 (1989 and 1990 are the years the ANSI and ISO standards specifying the new version of the language came out). One of the main changes of ANSI C was in how function parameters are declared. In post-1990 C, you declare the type of parameters directly inside the parentheses, and you also declare the return type of the function (this is mandatory since C99, although many compilers still assume `int` if the return type is omitted).

```
int compile(char *s)
{
    /* function body goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is the K&R style of declaring the type of an argument.

The function named **compile** takes an argument named **s**, whose type is **char []** and returns an int.

Most likely it is old code.

These days one would use something like this

```
int compile(char *s)
{
}
```

Comment: @JohnBollinger In the linked paper, there are no semicolons, so this answer is right. I'm upvoting.

Comment: @tos, the answer is **wrong** for the question as posed, but I have reversed my DV after realizing that the question does not accurately quote the source.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That is indeed true. However, I think it is the answer to what OP meant. :)

Comment: @tos-1, it doesn't much matter what the OP meant if what he actually asked is unmistakably different.  What happens when someone else comes by, sees the question in its present form, and thinks this answer responds correctly to that?

Comment: @john.  What do you perceive as being wrong?

Comment: @EvilTeach, this answer is no longer wrong, the question since having been edited.  In its original form, however, the question *did not* present a K&R-style function definition, but rather just invalid code.